# Having issue in creating week-calender pipline (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wan to create a small function, in which i can show table for whole week and header of table should contain dates for whole week. But the catch is i need a previous month dates too if they're coming in same running week. Same for coming month dated too show them also if they came in same running week.
for now I tried to create Pipeline for getting details from my array for current dates of whole week and previous month falling dates while showing table appropriately. But i'm facing issue in getting creating pipeline for this.

**Things that i need is :**

1. Proper day wise date for whole week.
2. It should handle cases for 28/30/31 days.

Table should like [image: date table for a single week]

**Code that i wrote:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'weekCalendar'
})
export class WeekCalendarPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(columnsData: VistaCalendar[], currentDate: Date): VistaCalendar[] {
    const weekCalendarData: VistaCalendar[] = [];
    const daysInMonth = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
    const startOfWeek = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 1);
    const endOfWeek = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), 7);

    if (startOfWeek.getDay() !== 0) {
      const prevMonthDays = startOfWeek.getDay();
      for (let i = 1; i <= prevMonthDays; i++) {
        weekCalendarData.push(new VistaCalendar(-1, '', '', [])); 
      }
    }


    for (let i = startOfWeek.getDate(); i <= endOfWeek.getDate() && i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
      const columnData = columnsData.find((column) => {
        return column.slots[0].date.getDate() === i;
      });

      if (columnData) {
        weekCalendarData.push(columnData);
      }
    }

    return weekCalendarData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get dates in current week

```js
let curr = new Date()
const week = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  week.push(day)
}
console.log(week)
```